# Calling a list of callable objects

Tags: python

Say I have a list of callable objects:

```
[<Python.Proto object at 0x1046ff940>,
<Database.Proto object at 0x10540c518>]
```

How would I loop through the list executing every callable, leaving the result in a list?

Comment: `[i() for i in l]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is fairly straight forward with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like:

```
results = [f() for f in callables]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo():
   pass

def bar():
   pass

l = [str, map, foo, bar]
result = [call() for call in l]
```

You have to make sure what parameters you want to pass to each function you can have it as a `dict`